# Input field text validation failing for summernote text area

Tags: angular, textarea, summernote, required

I am using Summernote for rich text editing. My input field has the required attribute.

```
  <input
              required
              id="summernote"
              formControlName="description"
              [ngxSummernote]="config"
             
            />
```

I have the Submit button. It will be disabled if the the text area is empty or pristine or invalid. code below.

```
<button
              mat-raised-button
              class="btn btn-danger pull-right"
              type="submit"
              (click)="submitDoc()"
              [disabled]="
                questionFormGroup.pristine || questionFormGroup.invalid
              "
            >
              Post Question
            </button>
```

**If I copy-paste some text inside my summernote editor, the button will get enable But if I do ctrl+a and remove all the text present inside text editor, the button should be disabled since there is no text inside text-area.** If I submit the form, the text are will contain values like below:

```
<br><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
</div><div>
```

How do I resolve this wrt to summernote. [Button enabled image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYsKl.png) and  [text area contents here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKPzK.png)

Here is my formGroup:

```
createQuestionFormGroup(): void {
    this.questionFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      heading: undefined,
      description: undefined,
    });
  }
```

Comment: couple of questions. 1. Why `formControlName` and `ngModel` together? 2. Can you please show the `questionFormGroup`, how it looks like?

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. I am just trying to display the contents the user enters in the same screen in a different place just to show user how the contents looks like. So I have added, I know that is useless, I can remove it.

Comment: @PankajParkar I have added the formGroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way of resolving your particular issue. Collect the HTML that is present inside your Summernote text-area using

```
var text = $('#body-summernote').summernote('code');
```

Strip off the HTML tags present in the var text.

```
 $(text).text()
```

You'll get rid of all the tags like  and

. You'll be left with plain text. Check its length using. Based on this, you can find whether the text-area is having some valid values or not. Calling .trim() as shown below is important.

```
$(text).text().trim().length > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem after pasting content directly inside `ngxSummernote` library textbox isn't updating the form control `touched`/`pristine` state of the `formControl`.

To fix the issue you can implement `onPaste` callback function inside `config`'s `callbacks` option.

```
config = {
  ...,
  callbacks: {
    onPaste: (ne) => {
      var bufferText = (ne.originalEvent || ne).clipboardData.getData('Text');
      if (bufferText) {
        // calling onTouched method to set formControl touched/pristine state update.
        this.summernote.onTouched();
      }
    },
  },
};
```

[**Updated Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-summernote-uhb13k)

Comment: Thank you so much @Pamkaj Parkar Can you check it by pasting some text which contains styles like some text in bold , some links and some italics. When you paste, you will find the HTML format of it below. Now do ctrl+a and delete or remove all the text, after u do so, you ll also see some HTML tags below the description text box. Hence, button will also be enabled in your code. Actually I am trying to solve the same issue.

Comment: @LohithJagadeeshRajesh please have a look at the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
isEmpty
```

Returns whether editor content is empty or not. You can implement this method to check contents.

The editing area needs `<p><br></p>` for focus, even if the editor content is empty. So Summernote supports this method for helping to check if editor content is empty.

```
if ($('#summernote').summernote('isEmpty')) {
  alert('editor content is empty');
}
```

Comment: This seems like a solution, let me check.